# Send email through Gmail SMTP to avoid local delivery attempts?

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, smtp, sendmail, gmail

## Background

We use Google Apps for email with our domain `example.com`:

```
[ec2-user@example ~]$ dig MX example.com
…
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            300     IN      MX      1 aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com.            300     IN      MX      5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com.            300     IN      MX      5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com.            300     IN      MX      10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
example.com.            300     IN      MX      10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
…
```

On the same domain we have an EC2 instance running, with Amazon Linux AMI
(Centos based). `sendmail` works fine for non-example.com addresses. However,
for example.com-addresses, it tries to deliver mails locally, which fails for
users that exist only on Google Apps. Interestingly this is despite
`local-host-names` being empty.

## Question

To avoid local delivery attempts, can we set up `sendmail` so that it sends all email
through Google’s SMTP server (requires authentication)? Would that be a good idea? Or is 
there a better solution?

## Additional information

- Also, it would be interesting to configure the server to send email to
  local addresses `root` and `ec2-user` to the Google Apps user
  `admin@example.com`. I guess, we would use mail aliases for that.
- FQDN:

  ```
  [ec2-user@example ~]$ hostname --fqdn
  example.com
  ```

  Of course, the actual server name is *not* `example.com`. It’s another `.com` domain.
- As requested by @AndrzejA.Filip:

  ```
  [ec2-user@example ~]$ echo '$j' | sendmail -bt
  ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
  Enter <ruleset> <address>
  > example.com
  > [ec2-user@example ~]$
  ```

Comment: 1) Is `example.com` set as FQDN of the host?  `echo '$j' | sendmail -bt` 2) Does the host accept email from internet?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip 1) See updated question. 2) All incoming email for the domain is handled by Google Apps, see MX records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your server `example.com`, the naked domain name. Thus many programs (sendmail included) take you at your word, and consider that the local server does *everything* related to that domain name.

To resolve the problem, rename the host. For this and a variety of other reasons, no server should ever be named with *only* its naked domain name.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, why wouldn't you name the server with only its naked domain name? This didn't solve the same issue I was having.

Comment: @MikeKormendy Then you are clearly _not_ having the same issue.

Comment: Regardless of not having the same issue, it would be beneficial if you provided some background on why no server should ever be named with only its naked domain name.

Comment: For posterity, @MichaelHampton addresses the reasons here http://serverfault.com/questions/599712/best-practices-for-fqdn-for-standalone-domain-is-a-two-part-domain-tld-okay/599725#599725