# Best practices for FQDN for standalone domain (is a two part domain.tld okay?)

Tags: fqdn

I've searched quite a bit and can't seem to find a straight, modern answer on this.

If I am hosting a domain, say, `mydomain.com`, on a machine which is going to solely be used for that domain, and there are no subdomains, is there a real, practical reason besides compliance to create an arbitrary hostname (i.e. `myhost`) just in order to have a three-part FQDN (`myhost.mydomain.com`) to satisfy some sort of RFC or convention that's expected.

This seems to make a lot of undue complexities from my perspective, and I'm not sure if there's an *advantage* to this or if it's just a hold-over from a time where all web resources came from a subdomains such as `www` and `ftp` which may need to scale to separate machines.

I don't use `www` on my domain, either, which is ill-advised for all I know from an administrators perspective (though removing it is the norm from a designer's perspective)...

Comment: You won't be on one server forever. May as well start now.

Comment: Related: [Definition of Fully qualified domain name](http://serverfault.com/q/609188/217116)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never give your server a name containing *only* the naked domain name.

The primary reason is that many services *use* the hostname internally, and may presume that the server is named separately from the domain name.

Among other things, this can cause [email to not be delivered](https://serverfault.com/q/575638/126632). It can also cause more subtle breakage, from programs which think your domain is `com` because you have named the machine `example.com`. A complete list of the things that could break is probably not possible.

As long as you have only a single server that you're [raising as a pet](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/03/18/servers_pets_or_cattle_cern/), you can probably work around the problems this will cause. But when you expand (you either will expand, or you'll go out of business) then you're eventually going to start [raising livestock](http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/pets-vs-cattle-the-elastic-cloud-story/), and at that point you're going to have to shoot your pet.

I always recommend keeping good habits and practices even when you don't strictly need to, since when you *do* need them later, they will already be ingrained.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only answer that gives an actual *reason* for the best-practice that I've heard recommended (with varying emphasis) on so many websites. In my case, it's a personal static website so I wont be expanding in the future -- but in either case, I understand that nothing but bugs can be gained by violating this particular assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create subdomains if you don't want to. It's very common practice to have `www` point to `@` so that if an internet browser is directed to either `www.domain.com` or `domain.com`, they'll end up at your front page regardless.

The reason people create subdomains is because they do other things besides just `www`, such as `ftp.domain.com` and `owa.domain.com` and `development.domain.com`, etc.

If you want to talk about the complications that would be introduced with this if you were using Active Directory, a split-horizon DNS zone and an internal network, that's a completely different story.  But you're not.

Edit: Michael Hampton's answer is way better than mine.

Comment: He's talking about _naming the server_, not DNS. I think.

Comment: Ok, well you could name your machine `mydomain` if you really wanted to, but it's an awful idea if you ever plan on scaling out, at all, so almost no one ever really does that.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the server's hostname. I've used a cname for www to @ for many years and rewrite urls to drop the www -- no problems there for my purposes.

I was setting up an MTA for the first time and had to create a FQDN and was feeling rebellious about this but Michael Hampton's answer has prevented my secession from the union of good sense.