# SSL certificate on cloned server, common name not same as server name

Tags: ssl-certificate, clone

I've cloned a rackspace cloud server and put it into a load balancer, whilst removing the original server. The site seems to respond fine but then I have a problem with the SSL certificate, as I'm getting an error message on https pages. The error logs say the common name is different from the server name, which I can understand.

When I do this process again, could I simply name the cloned cloud server the same as the original server or would this create problems? I'd eventually remove the original completely when everything is working fine.

Or could I name the clone server something else, but update the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostnames files to the same name as the original server? Would this be all that's required?

The domain name itself won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log error message wasn't pointing me to the real cause of the https page error. The reason I had problems with https pages was because my SSL cert was in the load balancer rather than on the cloud server so I was looking in the wrong place. Updating the load balancer was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

the FQDN that your client uses to access your service has to be same as what your certificate contains. Doesn't matter what your real internal host name is.

Comment: It's a cloned server so would the FQDN change?

Comment: The **FQDN is unique**, as all domain names are unique. See also [Definition of Fully qualified domain name](http://serverfault.com/q/609188/217116)

Comment: @kaska, Supposed that your web server has an internal name webhost.yourDomain.local, but as long as your users visit it as www.yourPublicDomain.com, you should get a certificate for www.yourPublicDomain.com. Cloned or not, what matters is how your users access the web site