# Why are some emails not reaching my inbox?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

I'm very new.

I set up email on my domain (postfix, dkim, dmarc, spf, dovecot... s-nail, Roundcube) by following reliable guides.

I now have 9 addresses, 3 different FQDNs. Emails from all addresss' are showing the following in Gmail: `SPF:  PASS with IP 0.0.0.0 Learn more DKIM:   'PASS' with domain *****.com Learn more DMARC:  'PASS' Learn more`

I was (apparently?) Emailed the login credentials for a control panel, to an API I'm using, but it didn't arrive, and there was no record in my mailbox logs of it bouncing. Here's the auto-response:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  sysadmin@*****.com
    all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts or (invalidly) to IP addresses
```

I verified my mailbox was working by sending to it from a Gmail account - seemed fine. An hour later I clicked the API panel's reset password link, and it sent an email to my mailbox which, I received!

Since I seem to have missed the first email (and every test Guerrilla Mail, I send) I'm concerned that I may miss others. I ran [this](https://mxtoolbox.com/MXLookup.aspx) and it tells me that my RDNS isn't valid. I used:

```
$ dig -x 0.0.0.0 +short                                                                                     
*****.com
$ dig *****.com +short                                                                                            
0.0.0.0
```

The values seem good. I don't know how to set up my mail server to live a 'mail' subdomain, thus am not adhering to best practices [as specified here](https://serverfault.com/questions/599712/best-practices-for-fqdn-for-standalone-domain-is-a-two-part-domain-tld-okay/599725#599725). Is this the reason for myfailed delivery?

I ran another test on a DNS app and it told me it got relay access denied error. I googled...:

```
The Postfix Relay Access Denied error message is generated whenever a Postfix mail server fails to authenticate the sender.
```

I vaguely remember blocking specific emails from entering the inbox, e.g. spoofed messages.

When I run [this](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx:*****.com) I'm shown: `DMARC Quarantine/Reject policy not enabled`

Thanks for reading.

What's causing the issue? Do I need to adapt my mailbox to live at mail.*****.com? If so, please tell me how, because I don't want to end up with email addresses such as `sysadmin@mail.*****.com`! :)

Thanks again

--- UPDATE ---

I redacted the FQDN, but am told it's necessary to include it. The FQDN is miri.cool, and IP is 138.68.146.190

DNS records

MX
mail.miri.cool
mail handled by
138.68.146.190
TTL: 14400

TXT
miri.cool
returns
v=spf1 mx ip4:138.68.146.190 ~all
TTL: 3600

TXT
_dmarc.miri.cool
returns
v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:sysadmin@miri.cool
TTL: 3600

TXT
default._domainkey.miri.cool
returns
v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAx0SMtP8XjZ9AaxlJLuRduHA0IrlQgyPw7qvzKdRUT18uew5smxinsV/m25tftarLXfPxOeeBHRhGCJMKhDHckQ4zlICNgzj7ZwPYvaTqFHvM6K55w9nzZ2thmqL6JoavRj4E5mf20bPutm1I6oNlUxkq0ZFCinzKz9rR+jFKea3zc4i12dPlU6ptFictXhybK3Eq76EZ8ShrFEECHpH5DrOI71hiwXyhi1yGOTkkZa3TOgLJ7ZL4H2VND647klf02nwSQbmJdEi4ZOiWLZSTfB0696T4jh412yGt96j/mCA0mRLtbsivK0bKSZ2VZooEu4Oo4dV3ZFiUabWB8BnkMQIDAQABCopy
TTL: 3600

MX
miri.cool
mail handled by
miri.cool
TTL: 14400

A
mail.miri.cool
directs to
138.68.146.190
TTL:
3600

CNAME
[www.miri.cool](http://www.miri.cool)
Is an alias of
miri.cool
TTL:
43200

A
miri.cool
directs to
138.68.146.190
TTL:
3600

NS
miri.cool
directs to
ns1.digitalocean.com
TTL:
1800

NS
miri.cool
directs to
ns2.digitalocean.com
TTL:
1800

NS
miri.cool
directs to
ns3.digitalocean.com
ttl:
1800

NOTE: My 'droplet' has the same name as another FQDN I'm hosting, which affects my RDNS name, so I've read.

Comment: Nobody here has enough info to go on to help. Perhaps share the IP and your DNA records for your domain to start.

Comment: The value `0.0.0.0`is definitely not good. But I guess you redacted that. Share the real data if you want anyone to help you.

Comment: Sorry! The FQDN is miri.cool, and IP is  138.68.146.190

Comment: I've added my DNS records, as well